# Curing with smoked salt

Tags: bacon, smoking, curing, smoke-flavor, pork-belly

I have a question about Ruhlman’s [home cured bacon recipe](http://ruhlman.com/2010/10/home-cured-bacon-2). I do not have a smoker and I know the smoking step is optional but I was thinking that if I used Maldon Smoked Sea Salt Flakes instead of the suggested Morton or Diamond Crystal it would give the bacon a nice smoky flavour. Has anyone tried this or has an opinion?

Comment: I use smoked paprika in my jerky recipe to bring some smoke to the party. It never quite measures up to actually smoking it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the smoked salt, but it would not impart that much smoked flavor and would be quite expensive compared to normal kosher salt. Since most wet-cured bacon available at the grocery store is flavored with liquid smoke, an easy alternative would be to rub the belly with liquid smoke prior to roasting as described at [The Splendid Table](http://www.splendidtable.org/recipes/curing-your-own-bacon).

As a side note, Ruhlman's recipe yields bacon that has a significant herbal flavor.  If you were looking for something closer to standard bacon, try a simpler recipe like the one from The Splendid Table or [this one](http://saltandsmokefood.com/homemade-bacon/) from Salt and Smoke Food

Comment: Great, thanks for the tips. I used Ruhlman's recipe (without the garlic, thyme or berries) with normal salt. I've just ordered some liquid smoke so I'll use that before roasting.